# Is it possible to store a binary string to memcached and then get it back in application?

Tags: string, binary, memcached

In my project i want to store a binary string (string like "010101010101") to memcached and then retrieve it back when needed,
it seems that i can store the string successfully to memcached as "get xxx" gives me a result similar to original one,
but when i use "memcached_get" function to get the result in my code, the return string is not the same to the original binary string,
the length of the return string is much shorter than the original one.

Who can tell my why, is it possible to store binary string to memcached?

Thank you and looking forward your replies~!

Daniel.

Comment: Not aware of any problems storing binary data to memcached itself, but without knowing the API used and seeing some code, that's all there is to say.

Comment: I have no idea how you store your data however it is possible that the count returns wrong results if a null byte (0x00 or \0) is included in the data. Many string functions handles that as the end of string marker.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Joachim and rekire,

I have solved the problem yet.
I used libmemcache c++ client in my code, the return of "memcache_get" call is char*, i just used string value = string(xxx) to convert the char* to a string.
But actually the binary string contains '\r\n' thus i just got the string before the first '\r\n' and lost the rest data, that's the key point to the problem.
Now i just used string.append(xxx, length) to get the whole binary sequence.

rekire, thanks for your tips, the cause of the problem is similar to your suggestion.

Thank you~!